# Чтение CSV в Java

Tags: java

Добрый вечер. Необходимо прочитать csv файлы, в которых такое содержание н-р: 
это означает, что в определенное время -time 2014-04-24 12:35:00 метрика tr_1 имеет такое значение 120. метрика tr_2 имеет такое значение 55 и метрика tr_3 имеет такое значение 890 (данные в разбросе)

```
time;tr_1;tr_2;tr_3;value 
2014-04-24 12:35:00;120;55;890
2014-04-24 12:40:00;86;555;689
2014-04-24 12:45:00;445;7866;235 
etc..
```

Написал код который выводит только содержимое просто:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

Data_To_Load d =new Data_To_Load();  
d.run();  
}

public void run (){  
String csvFile = "\\hh.csv";  
BufferedReader br = null;  
String line = " ";  
String cvsSplitBy = ";";

try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

    while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {

        String[] row = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        System.out.println(   
                row[0]  
                + "  " + row[1]  
                + "  " + row[2]);

    }

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} finally {  
    if (br != null) {  
        try {  
            br.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }
```

Не могу понять как можно сделать, так чтобы выводил содержимое файлов при чтении в таком виде:

```
time                  name      value  
2014-04-24 12:35:00   tr_1      120  
2014-04-24 12:35:00   tr_2      55
2014-04-24 12:35:00   tr_3      890  
2014-04-24 12:40:00   tr_1      86
2014-04-24 12:40:00   tr_2      555 
2014-04-24 12:40:00   tr_3      689 
2014-04-24 12:45:00   tr_1      445 
2014-04-24 12:45:00   tr_2      7866 
2014-04-24 12:45:00   tr_3      235
```

т.е данные в csv файле находяться в виде, т.е метрики tr_1 итд. находяться не в столбце а в строке. Как сделать, чтобы метрики tr_1 итд. в строке выдавались в столбец под названием name и значения этих метрик в столбец под названием value и упорядоченно, т.е н-р во время 2014-04-24 12:35:00 метрика tr_1 имеет значение 120 и другие значения остальных метрик в это же время н-р 2014-04-24 12:35:00 метрика tr_2 имеет значение 55 итд. потом уже другой интервал времени 2014-04-24 12:40:00 и опять точно также метрика tr_1 имеет значение 86, метрика tr_2 имеет значение 555 итд. до конца файла? Спасибо

*EDIT:*

Сделал следующее изменение:

```
List<Objekt> lines = new ArrayList<Objekt>();  
     String csvFile = "file.csv";  
     BufferedReader br = null;  
       String line = "";  
       String cvsSplitBy = ";";  
       Objekt data_set = null;  
          String[] header = null;  
          int lines_count = 0;

         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));  
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
             if (lines_count == 0){  
                header = line.split(cvsSplitBy);  
         }  
             else {  
                String[] temp = line.split(cvsSplitBy);  
                for (int i=1; i < temp.length; i++){  
                    data_set = new Objekt();  
                    data_set.setTimestamp(temp[0] + "\t" + header[i] + "\t " + temp[i] +"\n");  
                            lines.add(data_set);  
                }

                System.out.println(lines);  
                }  
             lines_count++;  
         }  
         br.close();
```

Получаю на выходе:

```
[ 06.10.2013 00:00  tr_1  100  
,06.10.2013 00:00  tr_2  250  
,06.10.2013 00:00  tr_3  25  
, etc...]
```

Посоветуйте, пожайлуста, как изменить (т.е где именно в коде это изменить) чтобы не получать скобки и запятые, а просто без них выводить?

EDIT: что надо сделать чтобы получить ещё и имена всех файлов которые считываются в допольнительном столбце, попробовал вот это только мне выдаётся имя последнего файла в папке, а не все файлы.

```
public static List<Objekt> run() throws IOException {

String path2 = "D:\\folder\\files";

File folder = new File(path2);

File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)

{

    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())

    {

        files = listOfFiles[i].getName();

        if (files.endsWith(".csv"))

        {

            files = files.replace(".csv", "");

            System.out.println(files);

        }

    }

}

List<Objekt> lines = new ArrayList<Objekt>();

String csvString = "D:\\folder\\files\\file1.csv";

BufferedReader br = null;

String line = "";

String cvsSplitBy = ";";

Objekt objekt = null;

String[] hdr = null;

int l_count = 0;

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvString));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    if (l_count == 0) {

        hdr = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

    }

    else

        {

            String[] temp = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

                objekt = new Objekt();

                objekt.setTimestamp(hdr[i] + "\t" + temp[0] + "\t"
                        + temp[i] + "\t" + files + "\n");

                lines.add(objekt);

            }

            System.out.println(lines);

        }

        l_count++;

    }

br.close();

return lines;
```

вот так мне выдает:

```
  >tr_klue    06.03.2014 11:30    1389    outfilename
    >tr_klue_lo 06.03.2014 12:00    1889    outfilename
```

т.к файлы имеют разные имена, надо чтоб выводилось имя каждого файла, н-р:

```
  >tr_klue    06.03.2014 11:30    1389    outfilename
    >tr_klue_lo 06.03.2014 12:00    1889    outfile1
    >tr_klue    06.03.2014 12:30    100     props2
    >tr_klue_lo 06.03.2014 13:00    89      colorak
```

подскажите пожайлуста где и что я неправильно делаю.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String filename = "hh.csv";

    try {

        BufferedReader fp = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        String[] hdr = fp.readLine().split(";");
        if(hdr != null)
            System.out.println(hdr[0] + "\t\t\t" + "name\t" + hdr[hdr.length - 1]);

        String[] cols;
        while(fp.ready()){
            cols = fp.readLine().split(";");
            for(int i  = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
                System.out.println(cols[0] + '\t' + hdr[i] + '\t' + cols[i]);

            cols = null;
        }
        fp.close();
        fp  = null;
        hdr = null;
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```